# Spikes (droplines) only turn up in first facet in ggplotly

Tags: r, plotly, facet-wrap, ggplotly

When I plot a facet_wrap() and put droplines to the x-axis, they only turn up in the first facet. Have I done something wrong or is this a bug?
MWE:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

gg<-ggplot(data = iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           y = Sepal.Width,
           color = Species,
           group = Petal.Width,
           text=sprintf("Petal Width %s<br>Sepal Length: %s", Petal.Width, Sepal.Length)
       ))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Species)

ggplotly(gg,tooltip = "text")%>%
    layout(xaxis = list(showspikes = T))
```

Dropline in facet 1:
[image: Dropline in facet 1]
No dropline in facet 2:
[image: No dropline in facet 2]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to share the x or y axis. So you could try:

```
gg<-ggplot(data = iris,
           aes(x = Sepal.Length,
               y = Sepal.Width,
               color = Species,
               group = Petal.Width,
               text=sprintf("Petal Width %s<br>Sepal Length: %s", Petal.Width, Sepal.Length)
           ))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(Species~.)

ggplotly(gg,tooltip = "text")%>%
    layout(xaxis = list(showspikes = T))
```

or

```
gg<-ggplot(data = iris,
           aes(x = Sepal.Length,
               y = Sepal.Width,
               color = Species,
               group = Petal.Width,
               text=sprintf("Petal Width %s<br>Sepal Length: %s", Petal.Width, Sepal.Length)
           ))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Species)

ggplotly(gg,tooltip = "text")%>%
    layout(yaxis = list(showspikes = T))
```

Comment: So this works in the direction in which there is only one axis, but not in the other one. Still the same problem. But you're probably right, maybe I have to assign something other than "xaxis" in layout, maybe "xaxis2" or something?